# What are the weight loss benefits of splitting meals into smaller meals throughout the day every couple of hours?

Tags: nutrition, diet, weight, body-fat

Are there any weight loss benefits for splitting meals into smaller meals, other than getting less hungry because of more frequent consumption? Apparently metabolism increases, but this is deemed a myth.

Comment: Can you expand on this question (what benefits are you wondering about? Are you asking if this increaseds BMR? If calories are handled differently if spaced out?) without broadening it's already possibly too broad scope?  Seemingly straightforward questions are rarely so. Please elaborate of the benefits you're curious about in this question. Thanks!